# Export Data into Separate Columns using PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, usaepay

I am working on a project to convert payment methods into tokens. To do this, I need to generate Method IDs using the customer numbers from my database. I have created a simple HTML form where I can upload an excel sheet with the customer numbers and receive a new excel sheet with the updated information (when submitting the form), including the Method IDs. However, all the new data is appearing in a single column. Can you show me how to separate the data into separate columns in the output?
Here is an example of the current output.

[Excel export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T7RQ.png)

Here is my code

```
<?php
ob_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{
    $wsdl = "https://sandbox.usaepay.com/soap/gate/43R1QPKU/usaepay.wsdl";
    $sourceKey = "_g6BALVW9vpPZ3jEqf5kwe4pIrqyvabY";
    $pin = "1234";

    function getClient($wsdl)
    {
        return new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            ))
        ));
    }

    function getToken($sourceKey, $pin)
    {
        $seed = time() . rand();

        return array(
            'SourceKey' => $sourceKey,
            'PinHash' => array(
                'Type' => 'sha1',
                'Seed' => $seed,
                'HashValue' => sha1($sourceKey . $seed . $pin)
            ) ,
            'ClientIP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );
    }

    $client = getClient($wsdl);
    $token = getToken($sourceKey, $pin);

    // Load the customer numbers from the uploaded Excel file
    try
    {
        // Load the customer numbers from the uploaded Excel file
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        if (!$file)
        {
            throw new Exception('File not uploaded');
        }
        $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($file['tmp_name']);
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $customer_numbers = $worksheet->toArray();

        // Generate the method ID for each customer number
        foreach ($customer_numbers as $customer_number)
        {
            try
            {
                print_r($client->getCustomer($token, $customer_number[0]));
            }
            catch(soapFault $e)
            {
                // Code to handle the exception
                echo "An error occurred for customer number: " . $customer_number[0] . " - " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            }

        }

        // Save the new Excel sheet with the information and Method IDs
        $outputFileName = 'output.csv';
        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Csv');
        $writer->save($outputFileName);
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.csv');

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }

}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

HTMl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Method ID Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Method ID Generator</h1>
    <form action="getmethodID.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file">Upload Excel File:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have already spent over 2 hours figuring it out
can anyone help me here?

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: While declaring a function inside an IF is allowed, it is normally dangerous and should be avoided.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a CSV file, or a Excel (XLSX) file? You have the content-type header for a Excel file, but appear to be exporting a CSV file. For CSV use `header('Content-Type: text/csv');`

Comment: I updated the line to "header('Content-Type: text/csv);"

but it still comes into one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `print_r` which will send the output of your function back to the browser, and setting the headers will instruct the browser to offer the file for download. This is the file you have showed in your screenshot which contains the output of `print_r`.

At the same time you are exporting a CSV file from php spreadsheet which will save the file on your web server in the same directory as the php script (assuming it has permission). You have not shown us the content of this file but it will be the same as your input file as your script never writes to the `$spreadsheet` object.

You need to write the content from your function into the `$spreadsheet` object.

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
// export headers
$sheet->setCellValue('A1','Ammount');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1','City');
// more headers ...

$spreadsheetrow = 2; // set a row counter
foreach ($customer_numbers as $customer_number){
    $data = $client->getCustomer($token, $customer_number[0]);
    // export data
    $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$spreadsheetrow,$data['Ammount']);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$spreadsheetrow,$data['Billing']['City']);
    // etc..
    $spreadsheetrow++;  // increment row counter
}
```

You can then save the file inline back to the browser:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.csv');
$writer->save('php://output');   // Exports inline to browser, rather than saving to file
```

Alternativly for CSV you can use built in PHP functions:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, ['Ammount', 'City']);
foreach ($customer_numbers as $customer_number){
    $data = $client->getCustomer($token, $customer_number[0]);
    fputcsv($data['Ammount'], $data['Billing']['City']);
}
```

Comment: just so I understand, am replacing the below code with the above CSV code?

$outputFileName = 'output.csv';
        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Csv');
        $writer->save($outputFileName);
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.csv');

Comment: Yes, although it will just output two columns as is, Ammount and Billing City. You'll need to expand it to cover the other fields you require. Given your data has an array of custom fields, and an array of payment details you'll have to decide how they map to the CSV fields if those arrays are variable length.